# Hide Audio Player

Tags: html, css, audio

My client has requested sounds upon page load. I tried to talk her out of it, but she wouldn't have it, so here we are.

On each page I have the following HTML:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://competenowdev.com/petrillo/paper.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

This plays the sound and displays an audio player. Is there a way to hide the audio player and just have it play the sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<audio autoplay="true" src="paper.mp3">
```

CSS looks like this:

```
audio {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you're looking for I just added an inline style to display:none.

```
<audio controls autoplay style="display:none">
    <source src="http://competenowdev.com/petrillo/paper.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:none;` to your css of the audio.